# Assign button image to links from db

Tags: php

php newbie. echoing out links to product pages, the following code works fine:

```
<a href="<?php echo $rows[$product_buy];?>"<p>Click Here for Details</p></a>
```

but, would like to change text link "Click Here..." to an image of a button.
tried different ways, searched around, still haven't figured it out

Comment: Change it to `<p><img alt="" src="/path to image" /></p>`

Comment: Hey, +1 for making your question succinct! Lotta people write a book for a simple question.

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff, I think you have to read about html elements and css style before using php...

Comment: know how it is, i try to be concise, thnx : )

Comment: yup, real familiar with html/css, integrating with php is my current labor

Answer (score 2):

You could simply style your link to look like a button (by giving it a class/id to make sure not all links are targeted) or you can put an `img` tag between the `a` tag.

```
<a href="<?=$rows[$product_buy];?>"><img src="path_to_img" alt=""></a>
```

Comment: so cool, that did it, thnx! i was missing one dang ">" in my best attempt